# Mocking the object inside the class without PowerMock

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I want to mock the object inside the class wihtout using Powermock. How can I do it?

I tried using spy but it didn't work.

```
/** SOURCE CODE **/
abstract class Parent {
    protected final Caller caller = new Caller();
    public abstract void call(Connection, Integer);
}

class Child1 extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void call(Connection con, Integer id1) {
        // some logic
        caller.getSomething1(connection, id1);
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void call(Connection con, Integer id2) {
        // some logic
        caller.getSomething2(connection, id2);
    }
}

class Activity {

     @Inject
     private MyConnection connection;

     public Response process(Request r) {
           Parent p = ChildFactory.getChild(r); // returns a child based on some logic related to p
           p.call(connection, r.getId());
           return new Response("SUCCESS");
     }
}

/** TEST CODE **/

public class Test {

    @InjectMocks
    private Activity activity;

    @Mock
    private Connection connectionMock;

    private Caller caller;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
         caller = Mockito.spy(Caller.class);
Mockito.doReturn(null).when(caller).getSomething1(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
Mockito.doReturn(null).when(caller).getSomething2(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcess() {
        Request r = new Request(1);
        Response r = activity.process(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(r.getResult(), "SUCCESS"); 
    }
}
```

I want to mock the caller object created in Parent class. It is going to be consumed by every children. I am not bothered about the result of the calls so I want to mock all calls (i.e. getSomething1, getSomething2) of callers without use of PowerMock.

I tried using spy but it is not using the spied object and it is calling getSomething1 and getSomething2 methods.

Comment: can you perfrom small refactor? or your tied as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ReflectionTestUtils#setField](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
     caller = Mockito.spy(Caller.class);
     Mockito.doReturn(null).when(caller).getSomething1(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
     Mockito.doReturn(null).when(caller).getSomething2(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());

     // ... obtain children here ...

     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(child1, "caller", caller);
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(child2, "caller", caller);
}
```

Or better you don't instantiate `Caller` instance inside `Child`-classes but inject via constructor for example

Comment: It is being instantiated in Parent. Am I missing something?